# stereocamera Calibration with matlab toolbox or opencv2

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

I'm trying to calibrate a webcam camera and I am using both of OpenCV and a matlab app for that but I'm confused.

First of all I calibrate them one by one with OpenCV code (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) but I couldn't get results better than reprojection error 1.2 for camera1 and 2.4 for camera2.

Using the matlab app I've got 0.5 and 0.4 for the two cameras, the difference is only that I used an online webcam for calibrating with opencv2 and passed saved images to matlab. After that I tried to calibrate a stereo camera using different OpenCV code and the error is about 2.7 but with the matlab app after optimization is about 0.4.

I don't know which parameters I can trust more with OpenCV or matlab APP?

Comment: Could you please share the code that you use for each one?

Comment: I ve shared the address of c code if go to the link you can see dear christppher.

Comment: Is this something that you can test? For example, at the link you gave, they used a chess board as an example and showed the image after calibration. Can you try both calibrations and see which one is better?

Comment: thank you for your reply but i think through the images we cant decide which method is the best there must be a scientific reason.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding you well. Scientific to me would be testing using known objects.

Have you read the following related posts? If not, please review them:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918315
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273571
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687231
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205557
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282861
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290086
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635540

Comment: Thank you so much those links were really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Reprojection errors are a very good indicator of accuracy. But if you want a more independent verification, try [measuring a planar object of a known size](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/measuring-planar-objects-with-a-calibrated-camera.html) and see how close you get. Alternatively, you can measure any kind of object of a known size with a stereo camera.